# Groups in Convolutional Neural Network / CNN

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I came across this [PyTorch example for depthwise separable convolutions using the `groups` parameter](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-modify-a-conv2d-to-depthwise-separable-convolution/15843/7):

```py
class depthwise_separable_conv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nin, nout):
        super(depthwise_separable_conv, self).__init__()
        self.depthwise = nn.Conv2d(nin, nin, kernel_size=3, padding=1, groups=nin)
        self.pointwise = nn.Conv2d(nin, nout, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.depthwise(x)
        out = self.pointwise(out)
        return out
```

I haven't seen any usage of groups in CNNs before. The documentation is also a bit sparse as far as that is concerned:

> `groups` controls the connections between inputs and outputs.
>   `in_channels` and `out_channels` must both be divisible by groups.

So my questions are:

- **What are groups in CNNs?**
- **In which cases do I need to use groups?**

(I *guess* this is more a general, not PyTorch specific.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking up an older version of the docs. 1.0.1 documentation for [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) expands on this.

> Groups controls the connections between inputs and outputs. in_channels and out_channels must both be divisible by groups. For example,
>
> At groups=1, all inputs are convolved to all outputs.
>
> At groups=2, the operation becomes equivalent to having two conv layers side by side, each seeing half the input channels, and producing half the output channels, and both subsequently concatenated.
>
> At groups= in_channels, each input channel is convolved with its own set of filters, of size: (`floor(c_out / c_in)`)

If you prefer a more mathematical description, start by thinking of a `1x1` convolution with `groups=1` (default). It is a essentially a full matrix applied across all channels `f` at each `(h, w)` location. Setting `groups` to higher values turns this matrix into a diagonal block-sparse matrix with the number of blocks equal to `groups`. With `groups=in_channels` you get a diagonal matrix.

Now, if the kernel is larger than `1x1`, you retain the channel-wise block-sparsity as above, but allow for larger spatial kernels. I suggest rereading the `groups=2` exempt from the docs I quoted above, it describes exactly that scenario in yet another way, perhaps helpful for understanding. Hope this helps.

**Edit**: Why does anybody want to use it? Either as a constraint (prior) for the model or as a performance improvement technique; sometimes both. In the linked thread the idea is to replace a `NxN, groups=1` 2d conv with a sequence of `NxN, groups=n_features` -> `1x1, groups=1` convolutions. This mathematically results in a single convolution (since a convolution of a convolution is still a convolution), but makes the "product" convolution matrix more sparse and thus reduces the number of parameters and computational complexity. [This](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/depthwise-separable-convolutions-for-machine-learning/) seems to be a reasonable resource explaining this more in-depth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I get at least an idea how it is working, even if it still not 100% clear. But what's the purpose of this, when do I want to use more than one group? What are the benefits of using more than one group?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although it was not directly related to groups, it was still interesting to see the numpy implementations. I still do not really understand how parameters can be reduced with more groups, but I think I need to look at a few more resources to fully understand how this takes place. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The same answer is well explained in this video: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVaRhZXovbw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVaRhZXovbw)